# Kernel power errors on Acer Aspire M7720

Tags: hardware-failure, kernel, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire M7720 with 12 GB RAM and 5 TB HDD.  Everything else is the same and I get kernel power errors.

My monitor says "input not supported" and I have to turn the power off cause I can't see anything on my screen.

Do I maybe need a bigger power supply?

Comment: Could you provide additional info re what you mean by "kernel power errors"?

Answer (score 2):

I have almost the same configuration. The problem is most likely with the graphics card. The ventilation channels get cloacked up with dust. Thus the graphics processor heats up to much. Just cleaned the graphics card fancase and refitted using cooling paste. Problem solved.

I am now trying to see which graphics driver version is best for this configuration. I noticed the standard (installed by Windows) drivers give problems when using the HDMI connection to my monitor. For as far as current testing goes, the latest (dec 2012) version for Windows 7 / Windows 8 provides the most stable config.